# Mongoose throws error on second time with Schema hasn't been registered

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate, mongoose-schema

I have a schema design where users submit language translation requests. A translation request document has reference to user documents and properties are called "_requester" and "_translator". I want to be able to populate these upon performing some query on translation request collection. Problem happens when I do a certain query, populate the _translator and results look perfect. Then if I do the exact same query it fails second time with the error message saying **Schema hasn't been registered for model "User".**

Here is how this has been coded in my code. There are two files. One js file where the mongoose sits and another js file that uses it via the model some what like dependency injection.

**(mongoose-util.js)**

```
function MongooseUtil(){
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate');
    var Schema = {
        User: {
            userId: String,
            password: String,
            nickName: String,
            state: String,
            emailVerificationCode: String,
            avatarUrl: String,
            points: Number
        },
        TranslationRequest: {
            _requester: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
            _translator: { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
            to: String,
            from: String,
            textToTranslate: String,
            translatedText: String,
            state: String,
            requestedTime: Number,
            translatedTime: Number,
            gradedTime: Number,
            grade: Number,
            requesterUserId: String,
            translatorUserId: String,
            graderUserId: String
        }
    };

    // user
    var userSchema = mongoose.Schema(Schema.User);
    var userModel = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

    // translation request
    var translationRequestSchema = mongoose.Schema(Schema.TranslationRequest);
    translationRequestSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
    var translationRequestModel = mongoose.model('TranslationRequest', translationRequestSchema);

    this.getUserModel = function(){
        return userModel;
    }

    this.getTranslationRequestModel = function(){
        return translationRequestModel;
    }
}

module.exports = new MongooseUtil();
```

**(translation-request-service.js)**

```
function TranslationRequestService(){
    var mongooseUtil = require('../../../utils/mongoose-util/mongoose-util');
    var TranslationRequest = mongooseUtil.getTranslationRequestModel();
    var _this = this;

    this.getTranslationResultById = function(id){
        return TranslationRequest.findOne({ _id: id })
            .populate('_translator', 'nickName avatarUrl')
            .exec();
    }
}

module.exports = new TranslationRequestService();
```

**(how the handler is being used)**

```
// following lines are executed twice by user's repeated action on UI
var service = require('./translation-request-service);
service.getTranslationResultById(id);
```

Comment: After some debugging in the Mongoose source code, I found that the User schema that had been registered is no longer there from the second time it is run. How could a model that was registered disappear? Am I using Mongoose incorrectly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by immediately cloning the returned result and running my logic. I still don't know what could have caused the problem. All I am doing is getting the populated result off to my web-socket to the client.